# SwiftUI @Binding Integer value check type error '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'

Tags: swiftui, binding

I'm wrapping my head around SwiftUI binding values and I'm stuck trying to check that an Integer doesn't equal 0. When using the following code I get the error `type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'`. I've also tried wrapping the Int around an object but the same error happened. Can you only use binding for Bools?

```
@State private var contentToPresent: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        if contentToPresent.wrappedValue != 0 {
            showView(id: $contentToPresent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Does it need to be all included as if I remove the if block above the remaining view renders and works without any issue. Plus, if I change contentToPresent to a bool it works, so the issue isn't the other code it's the Integer check on a binding value.

Comment: just skip the `.wrappedValue` in your code.

Comment: As always, once you've written it in SO you solve the answer :). This was it after a clone of the underlying view to a new view and ensured all bound values were Int and initialised down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI we don't do any computation in the body method because it slows things down and can break structural identity. Instead, we do it in handlers and then set a state var that the body simply reads from. e.g.

```
@State private var present = false
let contentToPresent: Int

// body called when either this View is init again with a different contentToPresent or if present changes.
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        if present {
            View2(contentToPresent: contentToPresent)
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: contentToPresent) { newVal
         present = ( newVal != 0 )
    }
}
```

In child Views we use let properties when we only need read access and body will run every time the value changes. If you need write access you can change contentToPresent to be a `@Binding` var.

Note we usually use `NavigationLink` or `sheet(item:)` to present things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @malhal. In this use case the I'm already in a nested element.